# set Error message content from the static blocks magento2

Tags: magento2, error, success-message, error-message

I am setting error message using below code.

```
$this->_messageManager->addError(__('you must login to continue.'));
```

Is it possible to load the message from the static block content.

for example i created static block with some html content. that content i need to show in error message. Is that can be done?

Answer (score 1):

you need to try this code.

For phtml file you need to used this code.

```
<?php 
$customerror = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('block_identifier')->toHtml();
$this->_messageManager->addError(__($customerror));
?>
```

For block file you need to do code like this.

```
class Yourclass
{
    protected $cmsblock;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Cms\Block\Block $cmsblock)
    {
       $this->cmsblock = $cmsblock;
    }

    public function Yourfunction()
    {
      $customerror = $this->cmsblock->setBlockId('block_identifier')->toHtml();
      $this->_messageManager->addError(__($customerror));
    }
}
```

Replace `'block_identifier'` with your block identifier.

Comment: this shows with html?

Comment: how to call it in block file

Comment: you need to call static block content as error message, right?

Comment: yes, in phtml file its working fine, but how to call it in Block files? that is php files?

Comment: I update answer, Kindly check into that I specify, How you can call CMS block content into Block php file.